# Hash is not recognized

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

The colon hash syntax works:

```
{ abc: 5 }
# => {:abc=>5}
```

However, `puts {abc: 5}` raises an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
puts {abc: 5}
         ^
```

I am using ruby 2.0.0. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` is recognized as a block. Put it in parentheses.

```
puts({abc: 5})
```

or

```
puts(abc: 5)
```

or

```
puts abc: 5
```